# S-Control in Lightning

Tags: lightning-experience, lightning-design-system, s-control

I need some guidance. In my current project there is a S-Control button on Send Email button. When i try to use the page in LEX it is not working. Can any one suggest me how i can fix this. Here is the button code.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN"> 
<html> 

<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/functions.js"></script> 
<script src="/soap/ajax/12.0/connection.js"></script> 
<script language="javascript"> 
function newEmailPage() { 
var callingPage=new String(window.top.location); 

if(callingPage.match("p2_lkid")!=null) { 
var u1=callingPage.substr(callingPage.indexOf("p2_lkid=")+8,15); 
} 
else { 
var u1="none"; 
} 
if(callingPage.match("p3_lkid")!=null){ 
var u2 = callingPage.substr(callingPage.indexOf("p3_lkid=")+8,15); 
} 
else{ 
var u2 = "none"; 
} 
if(callingPage.match("email_id")!=null){ 
var u3 = callingPage.substr(callingPage.indexOf("email_id=")+9,15); 
var u4 = callingPage.substr(callingPage.indexOf("replyToAll=")+11,1); 

var qr1=sforce.connection.query("select e.Id, e.ParentId From EmailMessage e where e.Id='"+u3+"'"); 
var records_trn1=qr1.getArray('records'); 
var u2 = records_trn1[0].ParentId;  
var qr=sforce.connection.query("select c.Id, c.RecordTypeId, c.ContactId From Case c where c.Id='"+u2+"'"); 
var records_trn=qr.getArray('records'); 
var u1 = records_trn[0].ContactId; 
} 
else{ 
var u3 = "none"; 
var u4 = "none"; 
} 

if(callingPage.match("forward")!=null){ 
var u5=callingPage.substr(callingPage.indexOf("forward=")+8,1); 
} 
else{ 
var u5="none"; 
} 

if(callingPage.match("retURL=%2F02s")!=null){ 
var u6=callingPage.substr(callingPage.indexOf("retURL=%2F")+10,15); 
} 
else{ 
var u6=callingPage.substr(callingPage.indexOf("id%3D")+5,15); 
} 

var url="/apex/SendEmail?id="+u2+"&cid="+u1+"&email="+u3+"&replyAll="+u4+"&forward="+u5+"&retURL=%2F"+u6;
if(u2!="none"){ 
var qr=sforce.connection.query("select c.Id, c.RecordTypeId, c.ContactId From Case c where c.Id='"+u2+"'"); 
var records_trn=qr.getArray('records'); 

if(records_trn[0].RecordTypeId=="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"){ 
alert("This record has not been established."); 
window.top.location.href="/"+u2; 
} 
else{ 
//sforce.one.navigateToURL(url);
window.top.location.href=url; 
} 
} 
else{ 
//sforce.one.navigateToURL(url);
window.top.location.href=url; 
} 
} 
</script> 
<body onload="newEmailPage();"></body> 
</html>
```

I need some guidance how to make this work in LEX.

Comment: 11 years and you haven't even moved to Visualforce. I think it's time for an update. By comparison, there have been four major Windows releases since then.

Comment: That's just terrifying that anyone would even try.

Answer (score 4):

It won't. S-Controls have been deprecated for a long time.

I think the more important question is, what does this control do that you want to replicate in Lightning? It could potentially be replaced with a standard Quick Action or Lightning Component.

Comment: S-control is used to override the standard "Send Email" button which is calling a VF page.

Comment: OK, and rather than have us reverse-engineer from a technology no longer supported, can you explain the business requirements satisfied by this button that are not satisfied by standard features?